# Trigger for update column

Tags: mysql, trigger

i´m trying to create trigger for update column, resulting of the min value of other columns. My sql code it´s the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER t__price_final AFTER UPDATE ON market__combination_price
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CASE 
WHEN market__combination_price.price <= market__combination_price.offer 
THEN UPDATE market__combination_price SET price_final = 
market__combination_price.price;
WHEN market__combination_price.price > market__combination_price.offer 
THEN UPDATE market__combination_price SET price_final = 
market__combination_price.offer;
END CASE;
END;
//
```

But it doesn´t work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are wrong:

- While the `UPDATE` statement can be inside a `CASE` statement, you don't really need it. You only want to update a single row. And you have access to that row with the `OLD` and `NEW` keywords (values before and after the update. You can use `SET NEW.price = ...`
- To modify a value in an update trigger, it has to be an `BEFORE` trigger, not `AFTER`.
- The `CASE` statement (that has a `SET`) can be converted to a `CASE` expression (inside a `SET`)
- Finally, if the columns are not nullable, it would be simpler to use the function `LEAST()` instead of a `CASE` expression.

The trigger code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER t__price_final 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON market__combination_price
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET NEW.price_final = LEAST(NEW.price, NEW.offer) ;
                     -- if price or offer are nullable:
                     -- = CASE WHEN offer < price OR price IS NULL
                     --       THEN offer
                     --       ELSE price
                     --   END ;
  END ;
//
```